# simple android socket client

Tags: java, javascript, android, sockets, node.js

I am very novice in Android Java Programming, so it is hard to figure my problem up. I have simple node.js server, that just listen localhost:7000 and print any input into console (it works fine with my actionscript client). I need to do something simmilar to understand Android, just simple client socket sender, that write anything that i can view in my server log. Here is the code, i trying to use on eclipse Android emulator and if i use "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" it works without errors but nothing happens (server log would be empty), and if i change it to my server local adress (here is wi-fi local network and phone uses it) application just throw en error after big freeze then shutdown. Simmilar problem with phone.

**Client-side:**

```
package etc.supachat;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SupaChatActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        try {

            Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.34", 7000);



            //outgoing stream redirect to socket

            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();



            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);

            output.println("Hello Android!");

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));



            //read line(s)

            String st = input.readLine();

            //Close connection

            s.close();





    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

    }
    }
}
```

**This is manifest code:**

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SupaChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**And this is simple ui:**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/out_view"
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**
Here is eclipse console log:

```
05-05 18:13:49.172: D/AndroidRuntime(1452): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-05 18:13:49.172: D/AndroidRuntime(1452): CheckJNI is ON
05-05 18:13:49.921: D/AndroidRuntime(1452): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
05-05 18:13:49.950: D/AndroidRuntime(1452): Shutting down VM
05-05 18:13:49.971: D/dalvikvm(1452): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 7ms+1ms
05-05 18:13:49.971: I/AndroidRuntime(1452): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
05-05 18:13:49.981: D/dalvikvm(1452): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-05 18:13:50.491: D/AndroidRuntime(1462): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-05 18:13:50.491: D/AndroidRuntime(1462): CheckJNI is ON
05-05 18:13:51.231: D/AndroidRuntime(1462): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
05-05 18:13:51.271: I/ActivityManager(68): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=etc.supachat/.SupaChatActivity } from pid 1462
05-05 18:13:51.321: I/ActivityManager(68): Start proc etc.supachat for activity etc.supachat/.SupaChatActivity: pid=1470 uid=10035 gids={3003}
05-05 18:13:51.362: D/AndroidRuntime(1462): Shutting down VM
05-05 18:13:51.371: D/dalvikvm(1462): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 69% free 319K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
05-05 18:13:51.421: D/dalvikvm(1462): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-05 18:14:01.324: W/ActivityManager(68): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
05-05 18:14:02.033: W/ActivityManager(68): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{406a46a8 etc.supachat/.SupaChatActivity}
05-05 18:14:07.151: D/dalvikvm(137): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47K, 52% free 2817K/5831K, external 4863K/5566K, paused 84ms
05-05 18:16:19.360: I/InputDispatcher(68): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{407b8948 token=HistoryRecord{406a46a8 etc.supachat/.SupaChatActivity}}.  5036.3ms since event, 5035.8ms since wait started
05-05 18:16:19.360: I/WindowManager(68): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{407b8948 token=HistoryRecord{406a46a8 etc.supachat/.SupaChatActivity}}
05-05 18:16:19.491: I/Process(68): Sending signal. PID: 1470 SIG: 3
05-05 18:16:19.491: I/dalvikvm(1470): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
05-05 18:16:19.520: I/dalvikvm(1470): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-05 18:16:19.531: I/Process(68): Sending signal. PID: 68 SIG: 3
05-05 18:16:19.531: I/dalvikvm(68): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
05-05 18:16:19.580: I/dalvikvm(68): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-05 18:16:19.580: I/Process(68): Sending signal. PID: 125 SIG: 3
05-05 18:16:19.590: I/dalvikvm(125): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
05-05 18:16:19.610: I/dalvikvm(125): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-05 18:16:19.610: I/Process(68): Sending signal. PID: 128 SIG: 3
05-05 18:16:19.620: I/dalvikvm(128): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
05-05 18:16:19.630: I/dalvikvm(128): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-05 18:16:20.030: D/dalvikvm(68): GC_EXPLICIT freed 789K, 47% free 4557K/8519K, external 3520K/3903K, paused 112ms
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68): ANR in etc.supachat (etc.supachat/.SupaChatActivity)
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68): Load: 0.09 / 0.12 / 0.09
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68): CPU usage from 14302ms to 0ms ago:
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68):   0.4% 68/system_server: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68):   0.4% 128/com.android.systemui: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68):   0.1% 125/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68):   0% 12/pdflush: 0% user + 0% kernel
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68):   0% 332/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68): 1.6% TOTAL: 0.9% user + 0.6% kernel
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68): CPU usage from 678ms to 1270ms later:
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68):   8.3% 68/system_server: 3.3% user + 5% kernel
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68):     8.3% 98/InputDispatcher: 6.6% user + 1.6% kernel
05-05 18:16:20.720: E/ActivityManager(68): 13% TOTAL: 6.6% user + 6.6% kernel
05-05 18:16:20.750: I/InputDispatcher(68): Dropping event because the pointer is not down.
05-05 18:16:23.530: W/ActivityManager(68):   Force finishing activity etc.supachat/.SupaChatActivity
05-05 18:16:23.550: I/ActivityManager(68): Killing etc.supachat (pid=1470): user's request
05-05 18:16:23.550: I/Process(68): Sending signal. PID: 1470 SIG: 9
05-05 18:16:23.570: I/ActivityManager(68): Process etc.supachat (pid 1470) has died.
05-05 18:16:23.770: W/InputManagerService(68): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406c8c68
```

**Update 2.** Here is the server-side script, that works with actionscript-client (it is something like chat, that i write to understand new language and platform):

```
var net = require("net"), sys = require('util');

var names = Array();
var streams = Array();

var policy = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
"<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">" +
"<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" />" +
"</cross-domain-policy>\0";

function onStreamData(data){
    var current_stream = this;
    console.log(data);
    if(data.substring(1,20) == "policy-file-request"){
        console.log("asd");
        current_stream.write(policy);
    }

    else if(data.substring(0,6) == "[name]"){
        console.log("name");
        names.push(data.substring(6, data.length));
        streams.push(current_stream);
    }

    else
    {   
        var na;
        for(i =0; i<names.length; i++){
            if(current_stream == streams[i]){
                na = names[i]
            }
        }

        for(i =0; i<names.length; i++){
            if(streams[i]!=null){
                streams[i].write(na+data+"\0");
            }
        }
    }
}

function onClose(){
        var current_stream = this;
        for(i = 0; i<streams.length; i++){
            if(streams == current_stream){
                streams.splice(i, 1);
                names.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        current_stream.end();
}

var server = net.createServer(function (stream) {
    stream.setEncoding("utf8");
    stream.on('data', onStreamData);
    stream.on('end', onClose);
});

server.listen(7000, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Please post the error(s) and context (were you using localhost, network, emulator, device?).

Comment: I add some eclipse log errors. Application just freeze for much time then shutdown with "Sorry! Application didn't answer". I use my local PC as node.js server that simple listen 7000 port and log anything in console on incoming data. As an client i tried to use emulator on this pc and then Android smartphone, both of it throw simmilar errors. I tried to listen and connect 127.0.0.1 7000 and then tried to connect and listen my local ip adress (for actionscript client it all work fine).

Answer (score 2):

**Quick fix: Host computer can always be accessed from emulator with IP address: 10.0.2.2**
So you should use this ip address in android code to connect with host computer.

**Further Details**([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)):

Android emulator is not on the same network as on which the host computer is. Rather android emulator is on a virtual network, behind a virtual router. So the emulator cannot connect to private ip address of your host computer.(Since it is on a different network).

And when you use localhost(or 127.0.0.1) in android code, it means that you want to access the android device so it does not make sense in your case.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I change it to 10.0.2.2 and set server to listen 127.0.0.1, but it still throw the same error.

Comment: I could not understand what you meant by this "set server to listen 127.0.0.1"?

Comment: It is "server.listen(7000, "127.0.0.1");" - server-side event, that listen 7000 port on this local pc. Also i din't understand what do you mean by "logcat errors"? What is this and where i could view it?

Comment: @user1324420 For logcat follow this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html

Answer (score 1):

To run it on your phone you also need the following permission on you AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I'd like to see the server side since I see no other error.

Comment: Thanks for this permission, but it still doesn't work. I add server-side code in update.

Comment: Might want to try using simple java TCP sockets, ServerSocket and Socket would do the trick.