# How to connect to particular ip & port in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I am new in socket programming.

I want to get connected to particular IP (e.g.: 184.267.345.65) & port (e.g.: 53) in Android so how could it be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Example: Android bi-directional network socket using AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135438/example-android-bi-directional-network-socket-using-asynctask)

Answer (score 4):

```
Socket s = new Socket("184.267.345.65", 53)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135438/example-android-bi-directional-network-socket-using-asynctask), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384678/how-to-create-socket-connection-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464500/simple-android-socket-client) for complete example code

Answer (score -2):

```
URLConnection connection = null;
URL url = null;
InputStream is = null;
String mUrl="IP ADDRESS AND PORT NUMBER";

try {
url = new URL(mUrl);

    connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "SPECIFY ACCEPT TYPE");
is = connection.getInputStream();
String data=convertStreamToString(is);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("Exception while reading inputstream  From URL :"+mUrl, e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is more suitable to connect to a server via `HTTP` requests **not** for socket communication